# Does A AWS Transfer Family API Gateway Identity Provider Need To Use Terraforms `aws_apigatewayv2_api` or ` aws_api_gateway_rest_api`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, aws-transfer-family

I'm looking at the Terraform docks for setting up [AWS Transfer Family](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/transfer_server) and I see this example

```
resource "aws_transfer_server" "example" {
  endpoint_type = "VPC"

  endpoint_details {
    subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.example.id]
    vpc_id     = aws_vpc.example.id
  }

  protocols   = ["FTP", "FTPS"]
  certificate = aws_acm_certificate.example.arn

  identity_provider_type = "API_GATEWAY"
  url                    = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.example.invoke_url}${aws_api_gateway_resource.example.path}"
}
```

I then look at the terraform docs for API Gateway and I see [two](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_rest_api) different [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apigatewayv2_api) for implementing an API Gateway. Which Terraform API should I use to build this integration?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [custom identity provider documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/custom-identity-provider-users.html) AWS Transfer Family expects a REST endpoint and therefore you should use `aws_api_gateway_rest_api`.